# Server for showing my system to my client?

Tags: testing, webserver, temporary, web-testing

I've developed a website and that's working well on my localhost. I want to show it to my client by uploading it on a server for one or two hours, so that my client can access and play with it directly.

Is there a way to set up a temporary server on my computer, or are there any free servers that will keep my system uploaded for 2 to 3 hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should have a company server and website to promote your company.

You can put client websites on your company website at http://www.company.com/demonstration/client (for example).

You can email the link to your client, and since it's your website, you control the access.

2 or 3 days would probably be more appropriate than 1 or 2 hours.

Comment: thanks for help... but the problem is that I don't have a company I'm just a developer of my own.. is there any other way?

Comment: @Sikander: Do you own any website domain?

Comment: @Sikander: I hope you don't take this as an insult, but how in the world are you going to help your client set up a web site when you haven't even set one up for yourself?

Comment: no not at all... just a learning point.. but the fact is that I'm a BS student ... and now I think it's necessary to have a domain of my own.. but what to do with the current situation?

Comment: @Sikander: Can you set up a website on your school's domain?

Comment: I can but I don't think faculty will allow me to use the domain for my personal use